# Convert Numeric type to Double without parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a generic method to compute the mean of any kind of sequence (for example: List, Array) which contains any kind of numeric values (Int, Float, Double...), like this:

```scala
 def mean[T <: Numeric[T]](data:Seq[T])(implicit number: Numeric[T]): T = {
      data.foldLeft(number.zero)(number.plus) / data.size
  }
```

However, the division operation cannot be resolved. That is because the Numeric type does not have this operation defined (from the [ScalaDoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html)).
I want to convert it to double before proceeding with the division, but the method `toDouble(x:T)` from Numeric type expects a param. 
I have seen there is a type member for the Numeric[T] called  `NumericOps` that does implement the `toDouble` method without receiving any param. Could I  call this method.. somehow?

Comment: You maye `number.toDouble(data.foldLeft(number.zero)(number.plus))` or `import number._` so you can `data.foldLeft(zero)(_ + _).toDouble` - However, that is a wrong approach, because you are changing the **precision** of the input. You either have to chose [**Integral**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Integral.html) or [**Fractional**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html) instead of **Numeric**. Both will provide division, for a subset of numeric types.

Comment: Check [Generic Numeric division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351176/generic-numeric-division)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez But how  can I use the Fractional type without using `toDouble` too ?   I tried: def mean[T <: Fractional[T]](data:Seq[T])(implicit number: Fractional[T]): Double= {
      data.foldLeft(number.zero)(number.plus).div(data.size)
  }   but it still needs the toDouble to perform division

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement generic average function in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160280/how-to-implement-generic-average-function-in-scala)

Comment: @CristinaHG Consider solution by [Kolmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069625/5205022) which does not result in loss of precision mentioned by Luis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Double` precision is sufficient, try

```
def mean[T](data: Seq[T])(implicit number: Numeric[T]): Double = {
  import number._
  val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus) 
  toDouble(sum) / data.size
}

mean(Seq(1,2,3,4)) // 2.5
```

or using `Fractional` (but it will not work for `Ints`)

```
def mean[T](data: Seq[T])(implicit number: Fractional[T]): T = {
  import number._
  val sum = data.foldLeft(zero)(plus)
  div(sum, fromInt(data.size))
}

mean(Seq(1.0,2,3,4)) // 2.5
mean(Seq(1,2,3,4))   // error: could not find implicit value for parameter number: Fractional[Int]
```

Comment: You can just `sum.toDouble` Anyways, see my other comment of why this is a bad idea.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Does the loss of precision happen only if `BigDecimal` is passed in?

Comment: Loss in the sense of going from more to less, yes. But I was referring to loss in the sense of using a different one. Usually one thinks that moving from **float** to **double** would not be problematic. But since the return type has to be `T` then you have to downcast the division to `T` again, which could lead to a different result than if the whole operation would be done using **Floats**. But yeah, for most code that should not matter, but I like to try to keep everything in the same precision format, just to be sure.

Comment: You're missing all the `CanBuildFrom` fun, this will only work with `Seq` :)

Comment: @flavian well since the collection is only being consumed, no `CanBuildFrom` is required at all. It can be made more generic by using **Iterable** in `2.13` _(like my answer)_ or a **TrasverableOnce** in `2.12`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I know I know been waiting for it for a while.

Comment: @flavian Sorry, I did not understand what you meant with your message.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The simplification of the collections lib that finally arrived in 2.13

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using **Fractional**, it will preserve the correct precision of the input numbers, and does only one traversal of the data. However, do note that this only works for types that have a *"precise"* division, like `Float`, `Double` & `BigDecimal`. But does not work for numeric types like `Int` or `Long`.

```
def mean[T](data: Iterable[T])(implicit N: Fractional[T]): T = {
  import N._

  val remaining = data.iterator

  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(sum: T, count: Int): T =
    if (remaining.hasNext)
      loop(sum + remaining.next(), count + 1)
    else if (count == 0)
      zero
    else
      sum / fromInt(count)

  loop(zero, 0)
}
```

This was tested on **Scala** `2.13`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have to use `Numeric` why not just use `Fractional`, as that adds a div operation to `Numeric`.

You may find this of interest as they talk about the different options:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40351867/67566

Comment: Note that **Factional** will leave outside types like `Int` or `Long` that do not have a precise division.